# Display dynamic text based on GET parameters

Tags: php, parameters

I'm trying to learn PHP, and I figured I'd make myself a simple exercise of making a site that if someone goes to it, they get "Hello friend!" but if my wife (who is named Dawn) goes to it, she gets a different message.

Unfortunately, it's always showing up as blank and I'm not really sure why.

I know it works for index.html with just text, and I know it works for index.php as long as I have no `<?php` tag in it (just text works). But when I try to make it actual php, it just fails.

- I'd like `site/index.php` to yield
  "Hello friend!"
- I'd like `site/index.php?who=Bob` to
  yield "Hello friend!"
- I'd like `site/index.php?who=Dawn` to
  yield "Hello Dawn! I love you!"

Here's what I have:

```
<?php
print 'Hello ';
$who = $_GET("who");
if($who && $who == "Dawn")
    print "Dawn! I love you!";
else
    print "friend!";
/>
```

So, what's wrong?

Comment: @Downvoter I'm curious as to why you've downvoted my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access to arrays ([`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is an array), like in Java, uses square brackets:

```
$who = $_GET['who'];
```

Also `if($who)` evaluates to true if `$who` is non-false, to check it's set you need to use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset):

```
if(isset($who) && $who == "Dawn")
```

Last, as noted by @Shivan, the end tag should be `?>`, not `/>`.

Comment: $_GET is an array? I see. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: That is definitely useful. However, it still doesn't even print the "Hello " from the first line.

Comment: @karim Thanks for that clarification. I was thinking that it looked more like map indexing than array indexing, but I'm certainly flexible with terminology. A rose by any other name is still a rose, even if `import rose.*;` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple issues, should be:

```
<?php
print 'Hello ';
$who = $_GET["who"];
if(isset($who) && $who == "Dawn") {
    print 'Dawn! I love you!';
} else {
    print 'friend!';
}
?>
```

More information:

- if possible, use single quotes for faster parsing
- it is a good habit to close if else case with brackets
- end tag should be a `?>`

Answer (score 1):

try this on for size:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello ';
$who = isset($_GET["who"])?$_GET["who"]:false;
if($who)
    echo "Dawn! I love you!";
else
    echo  "friend!";
?>
```

This checks to make sure there is a _GET value with key `who` or else php will throw errors.